# How to describe the feeling of a guilty pleasure?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm writing a story in which the POV character is talking about a guilty pleasure / vice, and want to indicate this. Something like, "talking about it made me feel _____". Is there a word or phrase I can use here? (I have in mind pretty much exactly the sort of things as in [this question](/questions/297837), but where that asks for a word/phrase to describe the thing itself, I'm looking to describe the associated feeling. I guess I'm looking for an alternative to "it felt like a guilty pleasure".)

- Not "bittersweet"; the character's 'negative' feelings aren't to the thing itself, but rather related to admitting that (s)he likes the thing.
- Not "rebellious"; that has a more positive connotation, whereas I'm looking more for "guilty" or "embarrassed".
- Not "titillated", precisely, as that doesn't convey the entire feeling, but maybe an adjective *modifying* "titillated"? ("Perversely"?)
- "Kinky" comes darned close, except I'd *really* prefer to avoid erotic overtones.

---

Edit: to clarify, I'm thinking of the sort of guilty pleasure that won't get the POV character *in trouble*, but would result in dirty looks if not outright teasing (or maybe worse). An analogy would be a member of high society that *enjoys* something that's both inappropriate to their social position (but would be normal for someone "lower class") and also something not usually considered enjoyable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps [indulgent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/indulgent), meaning

> allowing someone to have or do what they want, especially when this is not good for them

or possibly [decadent](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/decadent), which is

> If you say that a person or society is decadent, you think that they have low moral standards and are interested mainly in pleasure.

EDIT: In response to your edit, especially due to the mention of class, I think [vulgar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vulgar) could be considered appropriate.

> not appropriate, simple, dignified or beautiful; not in the style preferred by the upper classes of society

Comment: So... I ended up going with "timorously thrilled"... but *also* "vulgar", because that's just brilliant. Thanks!